# What does "Debug any CPU" in Visual Studio 2013 Express for the Web when using IronPython mean?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2013, ironpython

I'm trying to use IronPython with Visual Studio 2013 Express Web.  Whenever I first try to run the web application VS complains.  I can click yes and the webpages work:

```
This Project is out of Date:

Debug Any CPU

Would you like to build it?
```

VS also complained when I used regular Python 2.7.  This occurred with bottle, flask and a simple online Python page for testing.

What does this mean?

What problem(s) can this cause me in the future?

The IronPython installed is the latest version, 2.7.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Debug Any CPU" is the build mode that's set. Debug means non-optimized so that a debugging session will show operations in the proper order, the opposite is Release. Any CPU means that the code isn't compiled directly to CPU instructions but goes to an intermediate code, so it can be run on different processors.

Comment: Should I be concerned?

Comment: @johnny not at all, it's normal. It's just the environment's way of giving you what it thinks is relevant information.